# Android. Using the RealmObject with Databinding

Tags: android, realm, android-databinding

I'm using the `RealmObject` model for `databinding`.
It worked fine but now I want my views to update when data changes and I implemented `Observable`.

The model is:

```
public class RealmArticle extends RealmObject implements Observable {

    public RealmArticle() {
    }

    private PropertyChangeRegistry registry =
            new PropertyChangeRegistry();

    @Bindable
    public String getCountText() {
        return countText;
    }

    public void setCountText(String countText) {
        this.countText = countText;
        registry.notifyChange(this, BR.obj);
    }

    @Override
    public void addOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
        registry.add(callback);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeOnPropertyChangedCallback(OnPropertyChangedCallback callback) {
        registry.remove(callback);
    }
}
```

The problem is that RealmObject doesn't support the fields of `PropertyChangeRegistry` type.

Android studio says: `Error:(18, 8) error: Field "registry" of type "android.databinding.PropertyChangeRegistry" is not supported.`

Is there a way to implement this interface without violating `RealmObject` functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the [documentation of `RealmObject`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/RealmObject.html) states

> An annotation processor will create a proxy class for your RealmObject subclass.
>    The following field data types are supported:
>
> - boolean/Boolean
> - short/Short
> - int/Integer
> - long/Long
> - float/Float
> - double/Double
> - byte[]
> - String
> - Date
> - Any RealmObject subclass
> - RealmList
>
> Fields annotated with [`Ignore`](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/io/realm/annotations/Ignore.html) don't have these restrictions and don't require either a getter or setter.

Like this you can ommit the field from the proxy generation.

Alternatively you can use the `transient` Java keyword to achieve the same.

Answer (score 3):

It was enough to add `Ignore` annotation to that field.